# Exporting Motion Constraint rigging

Tags: rigging, export

I have a blender model of an aircraft which has been rigged using Blender motion constraint system. I am new to blender and need to get this model into another program (modo or 3ds max). Is there any way to export this file with rigging intact?

Comment: Only way to export rigging, intact or otherwise is through FBX file format, as far as I know. But from what I see it is all but reliable or faithful to original.

Answer (score 1):

No, Blender's constraint system is unique to blender and not portable to other software (in fact most program's advanced rigging tools are the same). Basic rigging (e.g. the bone heirarchy with parent/child relationships) can be exported with file types such as fbx.

Generally these sort of rigs are created explicitly for the program that the model will be animated in.